# Regex for three words not working?

Tags: regex

I need a regex for three words, seperated by spaces. I tried this:

```
>>>match = re.search('\w\s\w\s\w', 'cat dog mouse')
>>>match.group()
....
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Shouldn't `\w\s\w\s\w` accept "word word word"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it only accepts words which are one letter long. You are probably looking for `\w+`, and quite possibly the whole regex should be `^\s*\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s*$` with or without the optional surrounding whitespace `\s*`.